# Dealing with Firefox 4's new "data entered" confirmation dialog in Selenium IDE

Tags: firefox, modal-dialog, selenium-ide, confirmation, firefox4

I'm trying some S-IDE tests in Firefox 4 beta 7 that work fine in 3.6.  One thing I can't seem to figure out is an automated way to interact with FF4's new built-in dialog:

[image]

Anybody solve this one yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently running the test once and manually clicking the button causes it to not trip up in subsequent runs.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below link.

[Firefox 4 confirmation dialog in selenium 2.0b3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5602392/problem-with-firefox-4-confirmation-dialog-in-selenium-2-0b3)

I am also facing the same problem and still waiting for the solution. I recommend to downgrade Firefox or wait for the solution.