# Clicking Confirm Dialog Selenium in .NET

Tags: c#, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, specflow

I'm trying to make Selenium 2.4.0 Accept a Javascript generated "Confirm-Dialog", using Specflow and Firefox. I'm having trouble finding what I should do in my step below. (Tried to find an equivalent way of doing it in .NET from various Java implementations, but it isn't working)

```
When I click "Delete" on the App
    And I confirm the warning
```

Step definition...

```
[When(@"I confirm the warning")]
public void WhenIConfirmTheWarning()
{
    // WebDriver.Something?
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The way to confirm the alert in the .NET bindings is as follows:

```
driver.SwitchTo().Alert().Accept();
```

I have had this working with the Selenium .NET bindings 2.4.0, using Firefox 5.0.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Firefox 4.x or above? There seems to be an issue with Firefox 4.x and Selenium: [Firefox 4 confirmation dialog in selenium 2.0b3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5602392/problem-with-firefox-4-confirmation-dialog-in-selenium-2-0b3) 
The suggested solution is to migrate to Selenium/WebDriver.

Comment: Yeah, I use Selenium 2.4.0 and WebDriver, with Firefox 5.0.1.

Comment: I've solved the problem by combining the two steps into one and redefined "window.confirm" as some solutions say. Works good enough, but would be even cooler if you could make it press "ok"...